# How Javascript closure works given SAPUI5 dialog.attachAfterClose() example

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I would like to refactor a piece of code as following but I think I am having trouble understanding closure here.

Both `requestParam` and `reqParam` are `undefined` when callback function being called after closing the dialog.

```
_newConnection: function() {
    var reqParam = this.functionOne();
    var requestParam = {data: "data"};
    var oDialog = new sap.m.Dialog()
    oDialog.attachAfterClose(null, callbackFunction.bind(reqParam, requestParam));

}

callbackFunction: function(requestParam, reqParam) {
    if (requestParam.data) {
        reqParam.setId(requestParam.data.connectionId);
    } else {
        reqParam.setId("");
    }
    this.fireSomeThingElse({
        "change" : "change"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first argument of bind will serve as `this`, correct:

```
oDialog.attachAfterClose(null, callbackFunction.bind(null, reqParam, requestParam));
```

but it not make undefined arguments issue. I can not solve your exact problem because of lack of context, but I do this to bind operations with prepared arguments

```
var _newConnection = function() {
    callbackFunctionBinded = callbackFunction.bind(null, 1, 2);
    callbackFunctionBinded()
}

var callbackFunction = function(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1, arg2)
}  // => 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem here is the scope of the  `requestParam` and `reqParam` variables. They have local scope inside the `_newConnection` method and are not visible when `afterClose` event is fired. Try giving it a global scope.